# XText QuickFix inserting multiple word token

Tags: java, xtext

Given a grammar that includes a rule like:

```
SomeStatement: ... (tokensExist?=TokensExist)? ...

TokensExist: 'TOKENONE' 'TOKENTWO';
```

Next I create a QuickFix that detects the missing tokens and proposes to add them by modifying the model:

```
acceptor.accept(issue, "Add missing tokens", "", null, new ISemanticModification() {
    @Override
    public void apply(EObject element, IModificationContext context) throws Exception {

        // Locate the model element
        EObject goal = element;
        while (goal != null && !(MyStatement.class.isAssignableFrom(goal.getClass()))) {
            goal = goal.eContainer();
        }
        MyStatement stmt = (MyStatement)goal;

        // Set the tokens in the model
        stmt.setTokensExists(true);
    }
});
```

The problem now is that when the model is updated in the editor it appears as:

```
TOKENONETOKENTWO
```

instead of `TOKENONE TOKENTWO`, e.g. no space between the tokens.

This seems to be because the generated class `MySyntacticSequencer` has been generated to return a token this way:

```
protected String getTokensExist(EObject semanticObject, RuleCall ruleCall, INode node) {
    if (node != null)
        return getTokenText(node);
    return "TOKENONETOKENTWO";
}
```

I would like to avoid modifying the editor text directly and instead manipulate the model. Is there a way to do this? Can the generated token string be overridden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got this to work by extending the `MySyntacticSequencer` class and then overriding the `getTokensExist` method to return "TOKENONE TOKENTWO".

Is there a better solution?